# Xamarin Studio - Imageview

Tags: android, xamarin

with below piece of code I try to set an `ImageView` flexible:

```
var FindImage ="@drawable/Tabulator_E1_" +P2.ToString ();
var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
imageView.SetImageBitmap (FindImage);
```

In my `@drawable` I have several bitmaps such as `Tabulator_E1_1`, `Tabulator_E1_2` etc
Unfortunately `SetImageBitmap` doesn't take a string.  I am looking for a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use [BitmapFactory.DecodeFile()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile/p/System.String/) to load a bitmap from a string path

```
var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(bitmap_path);
imageView.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);
```

Comment: Thx Jason, nearly there. Unfortunately the imageView isn't set now. Could it be that "@drawable" (map under "Resources" isn't correct?